# Remove duplicates from variable using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a batch file. Here I assigned some values to a variable. I want to remove duplicate values from the variable.

```
@echo off
set test=1,2,4,1,5,6,2,3
```

Expected output: `1,2,3,4,5,6`

Comment: Must the output be sorted?

Comment: It would be good if we can see what you tried

Comment: @deepaksingla . . . What solution did you ever come up with for this question you asked here that worked to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 3):

If the output must be sorted, then you can use this batch script below that I whipped up with a little research and testing. I provided further study resources below as well.

### Script

```
@echo off
set "test=1,2,4,1,5,6,2,3"
for %%a in (%test%) do echo %%a>>"test1.txt"
sort "test1.txt">>"sort1.txt"
for /f %%b in (sort1.txt) do findstr "%%~b" "new1.txt" >nul 2>&1 || echo %%b>>"new1.txt"

set var=
for /f "tokens=*" %%c in (new1.txt) do (
    call set var=%%var%%,%%c
)
SET var=%var:~1%
echo %var%

for %%z in (test1.txt,sort1.txt,new1.txt) do (
    if exist "%%z" del /q /f "%%z"
    )
```

### Output Result

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

---

### Further Resources

- [For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [Sort](https://ss64.com/nt/sort.html)
- [Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- [Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [How to combine multiple lines in a single text file into one line, in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459131/how-to-combine-multiple-lines-in-a-single-text-file-into-one-line-in-windows/15459288#15459288)

Comment: I am getting below error ```FINDSTR: Cannot open new1.txt
1
2
2
1,2,3,4,5,6```

Comment: @deepaksingla Sorry for the late response, I added the logic to ensure that error is suppressed from the command line output that you see when you run it. Please give it another shot when you get a chance and let me know how that goes. The `%var%` value still equaled the same and expected output of `1,2,3,4,5,6` but due to the `findstr` and `||` command in that loop for conditions met or whatever, you saw that extra output but it's not really an error in this case so I added the logic to suppress it entirely..

Comment: @deepaksingla . . . What solution did you ever come up with for this question you asked here that worked to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 1):

This solution won’t sort the data for you, but it will remove the duplicates:

```dos
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET oldstring=1,2,4,1,5,6,2,3
SET newstring=

FOR %%a IN ("%oldstring:,=";"%") DO (
    IF NOT !test%%~a!==TRUE (
        SET test%%~a=TRUE
        IF "!newstring!"=="" (
            SET newstring=%%~a
        ) ELSE (
            SET newstring=!newstring!,%%~a
        )
    )
)

ECHO Old String: !oldstring!
ECHO New String: !newstring!
```

Example output:

```
Old String: 1,2,4,1,5,6,2,3
New String: 1,2,4,5,6,3
```

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question [how-to-remove-duplicate-comma-separated-values-from-variable-using-batch-file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/52424974/6811411) in StackOverflow.

Modified my answer to work with numbers up to 10 places length:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\09\20\SU_1359742.cmd
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set test=1,2,4,1,12,5,11,6,2,3
:: clear array test[], then fill it
For /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%M in ('Set test[ 2^>Nul') do Set "%%M="
For %%M in (%test%) do (
   Set "M=          %%M"
   Set "test[!M:~-10!]=%%M"
)
Set test[
Echo:    
Set "test="
For /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%M in ('Set test[') do Set "test=!test!,%%M"

Echo:%test:~1%
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\09\20\SU_1359742.cmd
test[         1]=1
test[         2]=2
test[         3]=3
test[         4]=4
test[         5]=5
test[         6]=6
test[        11]=11
test[        12]=12

1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12
```